# Using an artifact that is published to an Azure Dev Ops project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have configured a feed source for Artificats in Azure DevOps.  I can publish to the feed from the CLI and the packages show up in the Visual Studio UI successfully:

[image: image of visual studio ui]

The artifacts show as expected in the DevOps UI as well:

[image]

I have added the feed url as a source to the project within the nuget.config file.  However, during the Pipeline build I get a 401 error:

[image]

I *assumed* that having the build service as an authorized user would be sufficient, but clearly I'm missing something:

[image]

How do I configure this so that my pipelines have access to get the packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you add a [NuGet Auth task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget-authenticate) prior to the task running dotnet restore. It will add the right configuration for the build job.